# Internet Exploder "microsoft-edge:URL" redirect doesn't work for local html files

Tags: redirect, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have some old HTML help hypertexts (html pages ;) ),they are opened in Internet Explorer for some reasons that I cannot change.

Since I would like them to be opened in microsoft edge, this is possible only after a redirect that I can apply on the links that will open such pages.

When such html pages are on a server, it's quite easy to change the link `https://blabla/index.html` by adding the prefix "microsoft-edge:", as following:

```
microsoft-edge:https://blabla/index.html
```

When the URL of the link is written in such way, Internet Explorer starts Microsoft Edge, and the page is visible there.

BUT the problem is for other html pages are on the local machine. For example:

```
C:\blabla\index.html
```

In such case, I also changed the links pointing to them as following:

```
microsoft-edge:C:\blabla\index.html
```

and also

```
microsoft-edge:file:///C:/blabla/index.html
```

But the result is always the same: Microsoft Edge starts showing a blank page; it's like it does not receive the parameter with URL at all. Anybody knows how to change that? A blank page in Edge is useless, as you can guess.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is navigation to file:// URLs from non-file:// URLs is forbidden in chromium-based browsers. That's for security reasons. You can refer to [this article](https://textslashplain.com/2019/10/09/navigating-to-file-urls/):

> If a browser user clicks on a file:// link on an https-delivered webpage, nothing visibly happens. If you open the Developer Tools console, you’ll see a note: “Not allowed to load local resource: file://host/whatever”.

That's why the link to local file opens blank page in Edge. You can try the GPO workaround [IntranetFileLinksEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled) mentioned in the article. If it doesn't work, I think there's no other way to achieve that.